# Inline button telegram-bot-api

Tags: python, mysql, telebot

**как при нажатие кнопок добавлять записи в MYsql**
**например кнопка LIKE при нажатие должна добавляться +1 к к существующему записи**

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете PyTelegramBotAPI
то для инлайн кнопок все уже реализовано. 
Для начала сделаем разметку нашей будущей клавиатуры

```py
keyboard  = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
```

Далее создадим кнопку и добавим ее к клавиатуре

```py
button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Like', callback_data='like')
keyboard.row(button)
```

А дальше мы можем ловить нажатие на кнопку благодаря **callback_data**

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call):
    num = 0
    if call.data == 'like':
        ...
```

А дальше все ещё проще. Воспользуемся методом **edit_message_text** и изменим клавиатуру

```py
num += 1

keyboard  = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'Like {num}', callback_data='like')
keyboard.row(button)

bot.edit_message_text(message_id=call.message.message_id, text='text', chat_id=call.from_user.id, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Главное не забудьте проверять нажатия от пользователей, чтобы это не превратилось в кликер

Comment: MYsql ? как добавлять определенным записям like.у записей есть id мне нужно по id добавлять like при нажатие кнопки !!!

Comment: Я думаю вы понимаете, что больше числа 1 в этом примере вы не сможете увидеть)

Comment: "MYsql ? как добавлять определенным записям like": 


`UPDATE my_table SET like = like + 1 WHERE id = my_id;`